# Entity variable get list based on where

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am very new to EF. So I have an entity variable, how do I say give me all categories that start with 'a'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aCategories = from cat in context.Categories
                  where cat.StartsWith("a")
                  select cat;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like below, EF should translate `StartsWith` to `LIKE`

```
MyEFContext.SomeTable.Where(someTable => someTable.categories.StartsWith("a"));
```